# Dúvida ao buscar itens com Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Galera, eu tenho que buscar todos os itens de vendas concretizadas. Todo item é gravado com um CARRINHOID em uma venda, na tabela vendas eu tenho o CARRINHOID. Como eu pego todos esses itens? Fiz esse código:

```
public static List<ItemVenda> BuscarItensPorVendaId()
    { 
        //Aqui ele deveria pegar todos os ID das vendas
        Venda venda = new Venda();
        string vendaId = venda.CarrinhoId;


        return ctx.ItensVenda.Include("Peca").
            Where(x => x.CarrinhoId == vendaId).ToList();
    }
```

Ele só retorna o item que está no carrinho e não na tabela de vendas concretizadas! Me ajudem :(

Comment: Tentou dar include na tabela de vendas concretizadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi, de outra forma.

public static List BuscarItensPorVendaId()
        {
           return ctx.Vendas.ToList();
        }

Era só puxar a tabela toda e tratar na view  ¬¬'